# Logical operator to bit wise?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm working on a puzzle right now....trying to write 
`if (x==5 || x==7)`
With bitwise operations (in C). Been working on it for a while....can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Ps this isn't homework...trying to study for a test.

EDIT so the format would be something like
`if (x _ _)` with a bitwise operation in the blanks

SORRY need to specify, can only be two characters (operator or numeric value)
So `%8` for example

Comment: I think you need to try and learn how bitwise operators work then. There is a plethora of information out there, you have to want to learn it.

Comment: Hint: Try the `^` (XOR) operator. :)

Comment: I tried :( The issue is if I XOR with 111, for example, I end up with "2" for x=5 and "0" for x = 7. I need it to equal nonzero consistently ONLY for 5 and 7

Comment: `111` is a decimal number, not in binary. It's not that tricky. Think a bit harder. :)

Comment: Only 2 characters? That's absurd.

Comment: Is there some limitation on the value of x?

Comment: Well yes, kind of. X is not a multiple of 2....but does that do anything? I guess that tells us the first digit will have to be a 1

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of important. You should put that in the problem statement or you're going to drive everyone crazy.

Comment: Got it!!! That was important. Thank you.

Comment: LOL!!  Thanks for extracting that rather important piece of information, @CaptainMurphy =)

Comment: I doubt if there is any more limitation(s).  Otherwise it would be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7d = 111b and 5d = 101b

So bit 0 must be on, bit 1 is don't care, bit 2 must be on and bits 3-31 must be off.
So, mask out bit 1 and test for 101b

so your test becomes ((x & ~2) == 5)

Then ask Bing or wikipedia about "Karnaugh Maps" so you can do your own expression reduction.

Tom's answer below is also correct and is simpler. You could write

```
((x & 5) == 5)
```

and this is slightly faster. Perhaps I should have used a Karnaugh map!

Comment: Can only hold 2 characters (either operator or numeric)....if I'm getting your solution, that involves like 5 right?

Comment: What is this bing you speak of?

Comment: Bing is similar to Google but with full operating system integration on my phone.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but it works...if there was no 2 character restriction.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can AND it with '101' and you get the same results for both 5 and 7, which is 101.

Comment: SORRY need to specify, can only be two characters (operator or numeric value) So %8 for example

Comment: 0b1101 & 0b0101 is also 0b101

Comment: But if the number was say "1" (binary `0001`) it would still output something other than 0 when I AND it with `101`

Comment: @TomAngeloClemente Then it becomes `~2`, which is identical to Peter Wone's answer.

Comment: I know then I could XOR it or something, but that would be more than 2 char/operands

Comment: @paddy Just as i posted the answer, I know that we both have the same approach.

Comment: @pauliwago - provide more context. What can only be two characters? Are we manipulating char, byte, dbcc, unicode, short or ushort?